# Fast way to test if a port is in use using Python

Tags: python, sockets

I have a python server that listens on a couple sockets. At startup, I try to connect to these sockets before listening, so I can be sure that nothing else is already using that port. This adds about three seconds to my server's startup (which is about .54 seconds without the test) and I'd like to trim it down. Since I'm only testing localhost, I think a timeout of about 50 milliseconds is more than ample for that. Unfortunately, the socket.setdefaulttimeout(50) method doesn't seem to work for some reason.

How I can trim this down?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

How about just trying to bind to the port you want, and handle the error case if the port is occupied?
(If the issue is that you might start the same service twice then don't look at open ports.)

This is the reasonable way also to avoid causing a race-condition, as @eemz said in another answer.

Comment: This certainly makes the most sense, but I can't get the darned thing to throw an error when I bind the same port twice.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't throw an error until you try to listen()

Answer (score 83):

To check port use:

```py
def is_port_in_use(port: int) -> bool:
    import socket
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        return s.connect_ex(('localhost', port)) == 0
```

source: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116450/find-available-ports-on-localhost

**Note:**
connect_ex cann still raise an exception (in case of bad host name i.e see docs on [1].

[1] https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html

Comment: Sorry, I was actually using Python 2.7.13. Your example works with Python 3.7.0. Will delete my previous comment.

Comment: This answer interacts with already running services. Which is not necessarily what you want.

Comment: This will fail if the port is passed as  a string( It was in my case). As I can't seem to edit the post, please convert the port to int in the `return` statement as `int(port)`

Comment: this is not working on python 3

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me on Python 3.9. Make sure that `port` is an integer and not a string, per @Gru's comment.

Answer (score 29):

Here is an example of how to check if the port is taken.

```
import socket, errno

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind(("127.0.0.1", 5555))
except socket.error as e:
    if e.errno == errno.EADDRINUSE:
        print("Port is already in use")
    else:
        # something else raised the socket.error exception
        print(e)

s.close()
```

Comment: Not working. This code doesn't detect that a port is actually in use.

Comment: 1. where to print port is available? 2.can't one port be binded multi times using same addr or diffrent addr?Like SO_REUSEADDR for example?

Comment: Thanks for this this was very helpful for me to check if the default port for my app was already in use.  Based on whether it was it then kicked off find an unused port function which overides and sets a new port to be used.

Comment: The reason why is not working,. is because you are not running s.accept()!

Answer (score 3):

Simon B's answer is the way to go - don't check anything, just try to bind and handle the error case if it's already in use.

Otherwise you're in a race condition where some other app can grab the port **in between** your check that it's free and your subsequent attempt to bind to it. That means you still have to handle the possibility that your call to bind will fail, so checking in advance achieved nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Are you on Linux?  If so, perhaps your application could run `netstat -lant` (or `netstat -lanu` if you're using UDP) and see what ports are in use.  This should be faster...

Comment: :::Tests::: `netstat` seems to be work fine on Vista to do much the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 code to check port is in use or not

```py
# python 2
import socket

def check_port(port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    res = sock.connect_ex(('localhost', port))
    sock.close()
    return res == 0
```

Check [here for python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52872579/11286367)

Answer (score 0):

#### Check the available/Used Port

```py
def check_port(port):
    import socket, errno
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:        
        s.bind(("127.0.0.1", port))
    except socket.error as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EADDRINUSE:
            print("Port is already in use", port)
        else:
            print(e)
            print(f"****Port: {port} cannot be acessed****")
            return False
    s.close()
    return True

# Check port open for range of ports
for i in range (10000):
    check_port(i)
```