# Check If Port is Open in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, connection, port

In python 3 Given an IP address, I want to check if a specefic port is open for **TCP** Connection. How can I do that?

Please Note, I don't want to wait at all. If no response was recieved immediately then just report it's closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fast way to test if a port is in use using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2470971/fast-way-to-test-if-a-port-is-in-use-using-python)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer It doesn't mention anything about TCP connections.

Comment: `SOCK_STREAM` means TCP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Python3 example I got from https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-check-if-a-network-port-is-open-in-python

```
import socket

a_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

port = 8080
location = ("127.0.0.1", port)
check = a_socket.connect_ex(location)

if check == 0:
   print("Port is open")
else:
   print("Port is not open")
```

Comment: where did you specefy TCP connection and not UDP for example?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to check if a port is taken or if it's open:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

location = ("127.0.0.1", 80)
result = sock.connect_ex(location)

if result == 0:
   print("Port is open")
else:
   print("Port is closed")
```

In this, the `socket.AF_INET` specifies the IP address family (IPv4) and `socket.SOCK_STREAM` specifies the socket type (TCP).

Comment: Hi, this code is slow, I requested immiate result...

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple script

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 9003

# try to connect to a bind shell
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((host, port))
    print(f"Port {port} is open")
    s.close()
except socket.error:
    print(f"Port {port} closed.")
```

Constant `socket.SOCK_STREAM` here response for TCP connection.