# Python3 Don't wait for socket response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, port

Thanks for everyone who helped with: [Check If Port is Open in Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70500021/check-if-port-is-open-in-python3/70500067#70500067)

But I think my problem is still unresolved, When I scan all nearly 64000 ports it takes days to finish, while tools like nmap can find all open ports in 3 seconds.

1. I think the problem is that none saw my request about defining port to be open only if it wasn't **immediately** closed by the server. How can I reflect this in the code?
2. Looking at this code: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/port-scanner-using-python/
   I have noticed the use of: `s.close()` why I need it? Is it necessary if I want my code to run fast?

Comment: If you don’t close() your sockets when you are done using them, eventually your process’s sockets-table will fill to capacity and you won’t be able to create any more sockets in your process.

Comment: Thanks, what about not waiting for respponse, but let it immediate?

Comment: As for *immediately closed by server*, you’d have to define what “immediately” means.  Eg in ess than one second, or (???).  Also note that the timing of what the server does and when your client gets notified about those actions can be quite different things; eg on a poorly performing network the server might close the connection after 10mS but your code might not be notified for 2 minutes.

Comment: You can set a timeout on the socket before you call connect_ex. But you main problem is that you still are doing connects serially. You need to send out new connection requests before previous ones have completed.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk you mean using threads? should I limit max number of threads working at same time? are there any examples?